# Compare IP List to another IP List or IP Range

Tags: python, list, networking, ip-address, python-3.5

I've created a python project that scans an ip range (ie. x.y.z.0/24) and returns a list of online hosts.  It saves the online hosts list to file with just the ip's (ie ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2', '192.168.0.8',...].  I'm having trouble with this next step.  I'd like to compare this online hosts list to an IP range to verify that these are computers to eliminate other devices.  I have a DHCP Reservation List for computers that I can use. Is there a simple way to do this and update the onHosts list?

Comment: convert ips to ints, convert iprange to bitmask, see if ip is within that bitmask.

Comment: Any examples would be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is proposed solution you can try (it is a little bit bloated but I will edit it later hopefully)

```
def get_range(str_num):
    """ Converts string representation of number or range into (min,max) tuple """
    try:
        num = int(str_num)
        return num, num
    except ValueError:
        min_, max_ = str_num.split('-')
        return int(min_), int(max_)

def host_in_range(host, host_range):
    """ Checks whether given host belongs to given range (both are range representation """
    #print(*zip(host, host_range))
    for (min_h, max_h), (min_r, max_r) in zip(host, host_range):
        if (min_h < min_r) or (max_h > max_r): return False
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":

    hosts_str = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.10', '0.168.0.0', '192.168.1.10', '192.168.0.255']
    hosts = [x.split('.') for x in hosts_str]
    hosts = [[get_range(x) for x in elem] for elem in hosts]

    host_ranges_str = ['0-255.168.0.0-254', '192.168.2-5.0-255']
    host_ranges = [x.split('.') for x in host_ranges_str]
    host_ranges = [[get_range(x) for x in elem] for elem in host_ranges]

    for x in range(5):
        print(hosts_str[x], "in range", host_ranges_str[0], host_in_range(hosts[x], host_ranges[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Let me try this and see what happens.  I came across a simple way to convert IP Strings to INTs and back within ipaddress module. This makes the comparisons rather easy statically, but the program I'm creating is variable based on user input.

int(ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.0.1'))
str(ipaddress.IPv4Address(3232235521))